# How can I reference from DOM element to DOM element?

Tags: javascript

I know there are a lot of similar questions and I have looked through them. It was not enough. So.

I have this situation where I need to make a duplicate of an element and know the original element I have cloned from, so I do it like this which is ugly:

```
<div id="main">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

then

```
$(somewhere).append(
                    $('#main')
                    .clone()
                    .attr('src', 'main')
));
```

Now this is very ugly as I have attached ID from origin element I was cloning. In my situation I do not know if the element has an ID, so I could generate a random one and assign like this:

```
var id = $(element).attr('id');

if (!id) {
  var id = 'id_'+ Math.round(Math.random()*99999999);
  $(element).attr('id', id);
}

$(somewhere).append(
                    $(element)
                    .clone()
                    .attr('src', id)
));
```

My solutions seems very dirty for me and I there's a chance of collision of course, so...  I would like to know any clean way to refer to a DOM element from another element.

**UPDATE**

So in conclusion I have used jQuery's `.uniqueId().` and simply attached the element ID via `.attr()` like `$(el).attr('src', $(parent).attr('id') );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class names and modify the new (cloned) element with custom property:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
currentObj = $(".main");

//Object of the cloned element
clonedElement = currentObj.clone().addClass("cloned");

//Assign a reference with custom property
clonedElement[0].clonedFrom = currentObj;

$(somewhere).append(clonedElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query the DOM for an element with the ID that you've generated. If nothing is found then it's unique, if there is such an element repeat with a new random ID.

Comment: That's the same as I have described but I feel there must be another way.. Still +1

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
<div class="main">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

//Jquery Code

```
currentObj = $(".main");

//Object of the cloned element
clonedElement = currentObj.clone();

$(somewhere).append(clonedElement);
```

If you want to add a unique ID to the elements then you can do that like this from jquery1.9.1 onwards

```
currentObj.uniqueId();
clonedElement.uniqueId();
```

Comment: You don't show the second part of the question. He wants to know the origin element.